# What parameter type should I use to accept xexpressions?

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, xtensor

Suppose I have the xtensor xexpression `waffle`.

```cpp
xt::xtensor_fixed<double, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major> open = {{1., 3., 2., 5.}};
xt::xtensor_fixed<double, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major> close = { {5., 1., 6., 2.} };
auto waffle = xt::equal(open, close);
```

Considering the type of `waffle` is: `xt::detail::xfunction_type_t<xt::detail::not_equal_to, xt::xtensor_fixed<double, xt::xshape<1U, 366U>, xt::layout_type::column_major> &, xt::xtensor_fixed<double, xt::xshape<1U, 366U>, xt::layout_type::column_major> &>`

I want to pass `waffle` into a class constructor:

```cpp
class WaffleWrapper {
public:
    ??? waffle;
    WaffleWrapper(??? wafflein) {
        ??? waffle = wafflein;
    }
};
```

What would I use instead of `???` so that I can pass `waffle` into it?

e.g.

```cpp
auto waffle = xt::equal(open, close);
WaffleWrapper example(waffle);
```

Comment: You should decide what your class should hold. I presume `xt::xtensor<int,X>` or  `xt::xarray<int>`. This should also be you function argument. Normally conversions will then take care of everything.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Yes but casting to either xt::xtensor or xt::array slows down the program alot

Comment: Are you sure that it is the actual cast, or more the fact that your expression is evaluated? In any case I think that unless in very urgent case a class should own its own data, so I don't see how you could avoid evaluating the expression.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Ohh I see what you mean, so my expression was not being evaluated till I called the variable? That explains the hefty type name. Sorry I'm still fairly new to C++, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, it's stated here under xexpression. My bad https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expression.html

Comment: Alright. It is also a library specific thing, so makes sense that you did not know. If you convert your question to a complete minimal example (where you specify `open` and `close`, then I can answer, for others to benefit as well.

Comment: @TomdeGeus I have changed the question to specify xexpressions.

Comment: To convert this in an excellent question I would suggest that you change the input from the file (that exists only on your system) you specify some simple array by hand (or use e.g. `xt::arange`). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I commented, as a rule-of-thumb your class should own its data. You should thus create a data-container, which will force the evaluation of the `xfunction`. Thereafter you run no risk on pointing to data that may have gone out-of-scope.

If you are worried about loosing the ability to use the fixedness of your array you could consider templating the class:

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xfixed.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

template<class T>
class WaffleWrapper {
public:
    T waffle;

    WaffleWrapper(const T& wafflein) {
        waffle = wafflein;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using fixed_double = xt::xtensor_fixed<double, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major>;
    using fixed_int = xt::xtensor_fixed<int, xt::xshape<1, 4>, xt::layout_type::column_major>;

    fixed_double open = {{1., 3., 2., 5.}};
    fixed_double close = {{5., 1., 6., 2.}};
    auto waffle = xt::equal(open, close);

    WaffleWrapper<fixed_int> example(waffle);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I abbreviated your typenames for readability.

Comment: Thanks for all the help mate! "as a rule-of-thumb your class should own its data", what are the dangers of not evaluating the data?

Comment: You can image that by the time that you evaluate your expression the objects on which it is evaluated have gone out-of-scope. This will result in things like a segmentation, or more probably a wrong results. You should thereby keep in mind that your expression has no notion of the objects being alive, neither any ownership over them. Same goes e.g. for raw pointers.